# JQGrid paging by group instead of rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In JQGrid, I am using grouping with 3-15 rows per group. However, with pagination set to 25 rows per page, it will only show 3 or 4 groups, with the last group split between pages sometimes. I know why this happens, but is there a workaround to list 25 groups per page instead of 25 rows per page?

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` (in case of `datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`)? It's important to know because it defines *where* the paging will be implemented (on the client side or on the server side).